# python logging config format

Tags: python, logging, configuration, formatting, python-logging

I am using the python logging module with a configuration file.  It is working but I would like to change the format of the output string.  Currently in the config file I have a line

```
[formatter_fileFormatter]
format=[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)-8s %(name)-12s %(message)s
```

which gives me output like this

```
[2022-12-14 11:21:50,247] INFO my_logger.mod1 This is an info log message from func1
```

I would like to remove the decimal seconds.  How can I do it?  Ideally I would like to use the f string method of formatting, which I have read is possible but cannot find an explanation anywhere which explains how.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To remove the decimal seconds you could try specifying a different time format in the format string for the formatter like shown below. This will use the `datefmt` parameter to specify the format of the time:

```
format=[%(asctime)s] %(levelname)-8s %(name)-12s %(message)s
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

If you wish to use the f-string approach you could try something like this:

```
[formatter_fileFormatter]
class=logging.Formatter
format=f'[{asctime}] {levelname:8} {name:12} {message}'
datefmt=%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S
```

This will create a formatter using the `logging.Formatter` class and specify an f-string format string.

Comment: Thank you.  I have spent ages looking for this :)

Comment: First suggestion works fine, just tried the f-string and it errors with ValueError: Invalid format 'f'[{asctime}] {levelname:8} {name:12} {message}'' for '%' style  is there something else I need to add?

Comment: Try this: `format='[{asctime}] {levelname:8} {name:12} {message}'.format
datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'`

Comment: That gives a similar message  ValueError: Invalid format ''[{asctime}] {levelname:8} {name:12} {message}'.format datefmt='%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S'' for '%' style

Comment: For those who are getting "Invalid format [...] for '%' style", just add `style={` to your logging config file.